# How do you input module into Postman?

Tags: json, postman, smartsheet-api

so I am trying to create API using Postman followed by the instruction given in Smartsheet API: https://smartsheet-platform.github.io/api-docs/.
I am able to access my smartsheet data using the GET, it shows me details of my columns and rows. So I continued with the tutorial, I started with the following code:

```
// Initialize the client

var client = require('smartsheet');

var smartsheet = client.createClient({
  accessToken: '----',
  logLevel: 'info'
});
```

and I get the the error saying

> Cannot find module 'smartsheet'

I have the smartsheet api package download on my desktop, but I am not sure how I can make use of it. any help would be appreciated. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Postman is for testing individual API requests (GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, etc.). You can't use/call an SDK (or as you've referred to it, "the Smartsheet API package") from Postman.

Also -- you should never post your Access Token publicly, as anyone can use it to gain programmatic access to your Smartsheet data. I've edited your post to remove the Access Token value but would nonetheless recommend that you revoke that token immediately so that it's no longer valid. Then you can generate a new Access Token -- but don't share it publicly!

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for the comment and editing my post to remove the access token. I appreciated it